# How to solve AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, word2vec

```
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display, HTML
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
import pandas as pd
import re
import nltk

def word_similarity_scatter_plot(index_to_word,weight,plot_title,fig,axes):
    
    labels = []
    tokens = []
    
    for key,value in index_to_word.items():
        tokens.append(weight[key])
        labels.append(value)
        
    #TSNE : Compressing the weights to 2 dimensions to plot the data
    tsne_model = TSNE(perplexity=40, n_components=2, init='pca', n_iter=2500, random_state=23)
    new_values = tsne_model.fit_transform(tokens)
    
    x = []
    y = []
    for value in new_values:
        x.append(value[0])
        y.append(value[1])
    
    
    #plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5)) 
    for i in range(len(x)):
        axes.scatter(x[i],y[i])
        axes.annotate(labels[i],
                     xy=(x[i], y[i]),
                     xytext=(5, 2),
                     textcoords='offset points',
                     ha='right',
                     va='bottom')
    #plt.title(plot_title)
    axes.set_title(plot_title, loc='center')
```

While i try to run word2vec algorithm in the google colab, i m not getting the word similarity scatter plot and the error states

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-ce4c95c25962> in <cell line: 447>()
    450     loss_epoch.update( {dim: epoch_loss} )
    451 
--> 452     word_similarity_scatter_plot(
    453         index_to_word,
    454         weights_1[epochs -1],

2 frames
<ipython-input-46-ce4c95c25962> in word_similarity_scatter_plot(index_to_word, weight, plot_title, fig, axes)
    387     #TSNE : Compressing the weights to 2 dimensions to plot the data
    388     tsne_model = TSNE(perplexity=40, n_components=2, init='pca', n_iter=2500, random_state=23)
--> 389     new_values = tsne_model.fit_transform(tokens)
    390 
    391     x = []

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/manifold/_t_sne.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
   1116         """
   1117         self._validate_params()
-> 1118         self._check_params_vs_input(X)
   1119         embedding = self._fit(X)
   1120         self.embedding_ = embedding

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/manifold/_t_sne.py in _check_params_vs_input(self, X)
    826 
    827     def _check_params_vs_input(self, X):
--> 828         if self.perplexity >= X.shape[0]:
    829             raise ValueError("perplexity must be less than n_samples")
    830 

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

What should i do to solve the error ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that `tokens` isn't supposed to be a plain list; though I don't know the library enough to be able to tell you what it's supposed to be.

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: I'm fairly certain `tokens` is expected to be a `numpy.array`

Comment: In line 829 you get "raise ValueError("perplexity must be less than n_samples")". I would verify that your input has more than 40 rows (as you set perplexity to 40 in your code example) and see if this resolves your error.

Comment: @ChristophH. i have already resolved the issue. Thanks for answering